# Vue js, Element Ui Checkbox, проставить все значения по умолчанию

Tags: javascript, vue.js

подскажите пожалуйста как проставить все значения по умолчанию в компоненте Checkbox. Делал таким способом. В принципе работает. Но сейчас появилась нужда использовать подобный компонент, но со списком значений в массиве на 200 штук. И мой способ уже не подходит, да и данные обновляются динамически. Может есть какой то способ установить флаг отображения всех значений. (На скриншоте element ui который использовал)

```
<el-checkbox :indeterminate="isIndeterminate" v-model="checkAll"
    @change="handleCheckAllChange">Убрать все
</el-checkbox>

<el-checkbox-group v-model="checkedType" @change="handleCheckedChange">
<el-checkbox v-for="(typePhoto, index) in typePhotos" :label="index+1"
             :key="typePhoto">{{typePhoto}}
</el-checkbox>
</el-checkbox-group>
```

```
const partFace = ['Горло', 'Нос', 'Глаза', 'Фото без маски'];
let app = new Vue({
      data: {

        checkAll: true,
        typeImage: [],
        checkedType: [1, 2, 3, 4], //предзаполненный массив для корректного отображения фильтра
        typePhotos: partFace,
        isIndeterminate: false,
      },
      methods: {

        handleCheckAllChange(val) {
          this.checkedType = val ? [1, 2, 3, 4] : [];
          this.isIndeterminate = false;
        },
        handleCheckedChange(value) {
          let checkedCount = value.length;
          this.checkAll = checkedCount === this.typePhotos.length;
          this.isIndeterminate = checkedCount > 0 && checkedCount < this.typePhotos.length;
        },
      )
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: чем не подходит добавление подобной строчки `this.checkedType = val ? [1, 2, 3, 4] : [];` `created`?

Comment: @Дмытрык а другого способа нет? Там просто 200 с лишним элементов в массиве. Пока пытался объяснить проблему, появилась идея, сейчас проверю

Comment: Вы не можете сдлеать копию приходящего массива?